# Download and extract archive on Windows

Tags: curl, cmd, 7zip

On Windows, how can I download a tar.xz archive and extract it without writing it to disk first?

This attempt:

```
curl -L https://www.example.com/archive.tar.xz | 7z x -si -so | 7z x -si -ttar -ofolder
```

Gives errors similar to this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Extracting archive: ERROR:

Can not open encrypted archive. Wrong password?

Not implemented
--
Path =
Type = tar
Code Page = UTF-8

Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0
100   144  100   144    0     0    144      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   214
(23) Failed writing body
```

It works when writing the archive to disk first:

```
curl -L https://www.example.com/archive.tar.xz -o temp.tar.xz && 7z x -so temp.tar.xz | 7z x -si -ttar -ofolder && del temp.tar.xz
```

Comment: In `cmd.exe`, if you wish to concatenate lines, you'd use `^` not `\ `. So type `curl -L https://www.example.com/archive.tar.xz ^`, press the enter key, and carry on typing your command line at the `More?` prompt. _You could of course just type it all on one line instead._ However this will not work in your case, because cmd.exe does not work like that, you cannot just link commands with pipes. Also, when you're downloading a file, what do you think happens? just cache in memory until complete and then wait there for you to do something with it, instead of writing it to disk?

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it in the question. The issue still applies, though :/

Comment: I asked what you think happens, when you download a file too?

Comment: `curl` by default sends the downloaded file content to `stdout`. It should hence be possible to send it directly to 7-zip with `| 7z x -si`.

Comment: The StdOut and StdErr from `curl -L https://www.example.com/archive.tar.xz` would be piped, not the target file content!

Comment: The `stdout` of `curl -L https://www.example.com/archive.tar.xz` is the target file, so that should be fine.

Comment: Okay, if the actual bytes of data which make up your binary file are really being output to StdOut, as you insist, what happens when you open a Command Prompt window and enter, `curl -L https://www.example.com/archive.tar.xz 1>CON`

Comment: I get this output:
`Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output <FILE>" to save to a file.`

Comment: If I do `curl -L https://www.example.com/archive.tar.xz 1>CON --output temp.tar.xz`, I can afterwards successfully extract `temp.tar.xz` using `7z`.